# Getting go-gin's handlerFunc of a pointer receiver using reflect

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a problem in getting HandlerFunc with reflect.

Below is my code :

```
type ServiceHandler struct {
    Name string
}

var handler *ServiceHandler

func init() {
   handler = ServiceHandler{Name: "test"}
}

func (handler *ServiceHandler) Handler1(c *gin.Context) {
   ...
}

func (handler *ServiceHandler) Handler2(c *gin.Context) {
   ...
}
```

So far so good. Now, I am using reflection to list all of my methods and pass them to gin router.

```
func listHanlderMethods() {
    handlerType := reflect.TypeOf(handler)
    for i := 0; i < handlerType.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := handlerType.Method(i)
        fmt.Println(method.Name)
    }
}
```

which gives **Handler1** and **Handler2**.

My question is here:

> How can I get HandlerFunc s via reflect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value to find the methods.  Use a type assertion to find the methods that match the gin handler signature.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(handler)
for i := 0; i < v.NumMethod(); i++ {
    if h, ok := v.Method(i).Interface().(func(*gin.Context)); ok {
        // Do something with h
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IbZEB3BVQlQ)